# Convert aac to mp3 using ffmpeg binary command in android

Tags: android, ffmpeg, mp3, aac

I'm trying to use ffmpeg binary to convert aac format to mp3 format in andorid
I am too referring to a example here: https://github.com/sjitech/ffmpeg-android

What I tried with failure is

p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/data/data/myapp/app_bin/ffmpeg -i /sdcard/chua.aac -acodec libmp3lame -ac 2 -ab 160 /sdcard/chua.mp3");

I make sure that "/sdcard/chua.aac" exists on my phone

I guess the problem may come from libmp3lame in the command which is disabled in ffmpeg binary when building before with the example but I'm not very sure

Please someone reveal what my problem is and how to fix it.

Comment: You should provide the complete console output/log from your command. It will show if your ffmpeg was built with `--enable-libmp3lame` which is required if you want encode with libmp3lame. However, ffmpeg supports another MP3 encoder, libshine, which may encode faster on ARM. Also, use `-ab 160k`. Without the "k" you're trying to encode 160 bits per second instead of 160 kilobits per second.

Comment: I tried to get the log from my command but I got empty in the ouput. The ffmpeg binary is a prebuilt by another not me. Do you know the way to build ffmpeg exculatable binary for android which I can adjust options by myself. Aslo, if you have an example to use libshine in a full command. Please share with me. Thank you very much in advance LordNeckbeard

Comment: I have no experience with Android. I looked at the link and it appears that the binary is built without any MP3 encoding support. You will have to compile ffmpeg yourself, along with any desired additional libraries, or find another binary, or output to a different format.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard Do you have a detailed tutorial that I can refer to and compile ffmpeg binary with customized options? I like to use executable ffmpeg binary as command.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know of any good tutorials for Android.